# selected option with PHP and AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to get an option will be selected using AJAX, here's my code :

t_budget_expense :

```
+--------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field              | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                 | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| department         | varchar(128)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| section            | varchar(128)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| budget_id          | varchar(128)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| carmaker           | varchar(128)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| carline            | varchar(128)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| phase              | varchar(128)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| purpose            | varchar(128)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
```

m_purpose :

```
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| purpose      | varchar(128) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| purpose_link | varchar(128) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

```js
$("a.badge.badge-success.editExpenseModal").on("click", function() {
  const id = $(this).data("id");

  $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost/bulus-ci/budget/get_expenseByID",
    data: { id: id },
    method: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      $("#id").val(data.id);
      $("#budget_id").val(data.budget_id);
      $('select #purpose option[value="' + data.purpose + '"]').prop(
        "selected",
        true
      );
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <select class="custom-select mb-3" id="purpose" name="purpose">
  <?php foreach($purpose as $pur) :?>
    <option value=""><?=$pur['purpose'];?></option>
  <?php endforeach;?>
</div>
```

Controller Budget.php :

```
class Budget extends CI_Controller {

//==========================================================
// C O N S T R U C T O R
//==========================================================
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Budget_model');
        is_logged_in();
    }   

//==========================================================
// DEFAULT PAGE
//==========================================================
    public function index()
    {
        $data['user'] = $this->User_model->getUserData();
        $data['role'] = $this->User_model->getUserRole();       
        $data['budget'] = $this->Budget_model->getExpense();
        $data['purpose'] = $this->Budget_model->getPurpose();
        $data['title'] = 'Expense Budget';

        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/sidebar');
        $this->load->view('templates/topbar');
        $this->load->view('budget/index');
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }

//==========================================================
// EDIT EXPENSE
//==========================================================
    public function get_expenseByID()
    {
        $id = $this->input->post('id');
        echo $this->Budget_model->getExpenseByID($id);
    }   

}
```

Model Budget_model.php :

```
public function getExpenseByID($id)
{
    $get_id = $id;
    return json_encode($this->db->get_where('t_budget_expense', ['id' => $get_id])->row_array());
}

public function getPurpose()
{
    $this->db->order_by('purpose', 'ASC');
    return $this->db->get('m_purpose')->result_array();
}
```

My goal is when the users click the edit button then Modal Form appears, which aoutomatically select the purpose field based on t_budget_expense, but it's not working with my current code

Comment: does `data.purpose` have required value ?

Comment: @Swati Yes it is

Comment: What happens instead? What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: @Nico Haase the result was nothing selected from the option value, it's just fetched the result from the looping script. I tried to change the value using val() on my ajax script and got nothing

Comment: And what have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score 1):

In  your select input view

```
 <option value=""><?=$pur['purpose'];?></option>
```

you are missing value of an option i guess it should look like

```
 <option value="<?= $pur['purpose'] ?>"><?= $pur['purpose'] ?></option>
//Note:value depends on your application requirement "purpose" or  "id"
```

Comment: Value must be the value from t_budget_expense which is the different table with m_purpose (table where the $pur var was fetched)

Comment: both table seems to have "purpose" column.Are they different ?

Comment: The different is, the one is master and the others is coming from user input

Comment: Whatever it is rendering select options without values doesn't make sense to me.secondly if there is no relation between two tables how would you know what is purpose based on fetched data from t_budget_expense

Comment: when user clicking edit button, it sends budget_id to controller & model via ajax then i get the purpose from there, the problem is i tried to fetching purpose list from master purpose then select one of them which is == with purpose field from t_budget_expense. For example : The purpose field from  t_budget_expense is "GENERAL", then attributes or Value of "GENERAL" from purpose master which have been fetched on the drop down list must be Selected / Filled, thats the idea, just don't know how to execute it

Comment: if you are passing "budget_id" over ajax then why are you comparing with "id"  in "t_budget_expense". what you have added in your query code and what you have in comments is contradicting results to confusion .

Answer (score 0):

```
    //controller
    //in edit function  you to send an id on click the edit button and if you are using route then the id will also pass in route. this id is the primary key id of t_budget_expense table.
    public function index($id)
        {
            $data['budget'] = $this->Budget_model->getExpenseById($id);
            $data['purposeArray'] = $this->Budget_model->getPurpose();
            $data['title'] = 'Expense Budget';

            $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/sidebar');
            $this->load->view('templates/topbar');
            $this->load->view('budget/index');
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        }
    //in t_budget_expense model
    function getExpenseById($id){
    return $this->db->where('id',$id)->get('t_budget_expense')->row_array();
    }
    //in m_purpose model
    function getPurpose(){
    return $this->db->get('m_purpose')->result_array();
    }
    //in view
     <select type="text" class="form-control" id="purpose" name="purpose" >
    <option value="" >Select purpose</option>   
            <?php foreach ($purposeArray as $purpose)
                  { ?>
       <option <?php if ($purpose->purpose == $purpose['purpose']) {
                 echo 'selected="selected"';
                 } ?> value="<?php echo $purpose->purpose ?>">
                <?php echo $purpose->purpose ?> </option>
                 <?php } ?>
                 </select>
```

Comment: hello, thanks for the answer, but it seems pure php, cmiiw
i need ajax to process teh backend here